# Firebase php invalid character value error

Tags: php, firebase, invalid-characters

Using firebase php, I am getting following error in a simple `$firebase->set($data,$location)` function.

> Uncaught exception 'Kreait\Firebase\Exception\FirebaseException' with
>   message 'The location key "rural foothills m.d." contains on of the
>   following invalid characters: .$#[]'

Is there a way to sanitize the value to avoid the error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you will see an error that says "*Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value. Perhaps you're using invalid characters in your key names*."

This error occurs when the fields you are trying to send to Firebase contain invalid characters. Firebase prohibits key names from containing:

```
. (period)
$ (dollar sign)
[ (left square bracket)
] (right square bracket)
# (hash or pound sign)
/ (forward slash)
```

To get around the error, you will need to manually assign names to the keys.

> **Reference:** [Common Problems with Firebase](https://zapier.com/help/common-problems-firebase/)